tcolorbox: vertical spacing to mimic regular paragraphs
I often use a tcolorbox with skin blankest to place graphics to the right of text. To that end, I would like to set the vertical spacing before and after the tcolorbox such that a paragraph in it mimics a regular paragraph.
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{1.15}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{tcolorbox}[blankest, colupper=red]
\blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}

\blindtext

\end{document}

The red paragraph inside the tcolorbox should have the same spacings as a regular paragraph. Is there a good way to reliably achieve that, possibly even for different \setstretch values and irrespective of whether the last line inside the tcolorbox contains descending letters?

Thanks for hinting at that earlier question! It does answer my question, so I will show the solution here to answer my question myself...

This question is similar to How to set a phantom box in tcolorbox? and the answer to it works here as well:
\begin{tcolorbox}[blankest, colupper=red,
    beforeafter skip balanced=\parskip,
    before upper=\strut, after upper=\strut ]
\blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}

